# swrl rules for data mapped

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, swrl

I have developed an ontology to identify patients and also mapped it to my sample SQL database (include 100 patients). It means we don’t have any individuals in ontology. So, how can I run similar swrl rule for the following  sparql query in the rule tab:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?x WHERE {
  { ?x :PatientCode ?c .
    FILTER (?c = "1"^^xsd:double). }
  OPTIONAL {
    ?x :hasRiskFactor ?p.
    ?p :MeasureType ?u.
    FILTER( ?u = "ENDOC"^^xsd:String ||
            ?u = "DIETITIAN"^^xsd:String ||
            ?u = "ATTPOD"^^xsd:String ||
            ?u = "ATTOPH"^^xsd:String)
  }
  FILTER (!bound(?u))
}
```